# Monero GUI is unable to start monerod on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, daemon, error-log

I just installed the **Monero GUI 0.13.0.4 Beryllium Bullet** on Ubuntu 18.04, and I also installed the `libhidapi-libusb` library.

When I start the Monero GUI, it fails to start the daemon.

The logs report this:

```
Error: Couldn't connect to the daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
```

The weird thing is when I start monerod manually and then start the GUI when monerod is already running, everything works just fine.

Is this a bug or did I forget something?

It isn't even a problem, just an annoyance, but it would be nice if I can fix this.

Thanks in advance for any advice I can get :)

***Additional info:*** I have my blockchain folder on my Synology NAS. In Windows, **monerod** has no trouble finding the folder, but in Linux, after I enter the path, I get an error message the target has zero space left. No idea why that is.

Comment: Ow yeah forgot, it's on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: If you run `monerod` manually, from which folder does `monerod` open the blockchain? Also, the database technology used by Monero (lmdb) requires mmap. Does your Synology NAS support that? Lastly, what path did you specify as `Blockchain location` on the `Settings` page of the GUI?